# model object not iterable

Tags: django

template.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<body>
{% block content %}

<form action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}


<table align="center" style="margin-left:60px";>

        <p>{{KEBReading_form.as_table}}</p>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input name="KEBsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Reading" id="_KEBsubmit1"/> </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" >{{KEBMessage}} </td></tr>
</table>
</form>


<table border="1">
<p> KEB Reading as on Month jan and year 2012</p>
<tr>
<th>Date </th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>True Power Reading</th>
<th>Apparent Power Reading</th>
<th>True Power consumed</th>
<th>Voltage Reading</th>
<th>Power Factor</th>
 </tr>



{% for item in q2 %}
 <tr>
 <td>{{item.date}}</td>
 <td>{{item.time}}</td>
 <td>{{item.truepower_reading}}</td>
 <td>{{item.apparentpower_reading}}</td>
  <td>{{item.truepower_consumed}}</td>
  <td>{{item.voltage_reading}}</td>
    <td> {{item.powerfactor}}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}

 </table>
```

{% endblock content %}

views.py

```
 def KEBReading1(request):
#form2 = KEBReading.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":


    form = KEBReading_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        prevdate=KEBReading.objects.latest("date")
       # Model.objects.latest('field')
        print prevdate.date
        print prevdate.time
        # q1 = KEBReading.objects.get(datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(0))

        kr_truepower_reading = form.cleaned_data["truepower_reading"]
        kr_apparentpower_reading = form.cleaned_data["apparentpower_reading"]
        truepower_consumed1=kr_truepower_reading-prevdate.truepower_reading
        powerfactor1=((kr_truepower_reading-prevdate.truepower_reading)/(kr_apparentpower_reading-prevdate.apparentpower_reading))
        #instance=truepower_consumed,powerfactor
  ## replace form.save() with following lines



        form1=form.save(commit=False)
        #form1.calculate(truepower_consumed1,powerfactor1)
        form1.truepower_consumed=truepower_consumed1
        form1.powerfactor=powerfactor1
        print form1.powerfactor
        form1.save()



        q2=KEBReading.objects.latest("date")

        context={'KEBReading_form':form,'q2':q2}
        return render_to_response('keb.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

else:
    form = KEBReading_form()

return render_to_response('keb.html',{'KEBReading_form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

i want to display all readings in a table whic i calculated through the views in the template. i get model object not iterable while using for loop to iterate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. First, as Aidan correctly noted `KEBReading.objects.latest("date")` this will return an object, not a collection or iterable.
2. Secondly, you aren't assigning any of the fields that you are calculating in view. `truepower_consumed1=kr_truepower_reading-prevdate.truepower_reading` doesn't assign it to your object that you retrieved (your `q2`). I'm not sure if this is intentional. However, I suspect you want to return to your template the instance of the form, not another record from the table. You need to update your question.

To fix these problems immediately:

```
 <tr>
 <td>{{q2.date}}</td>
 <td>{{q2.time}}</td>
 <td>{{q2.truepower_reading}}</td>
 <td>{{q2.apparentpower_reading}}</td>
 <td>{{q2.truepower_consumed}}</td>
 <td>{{q2.voltage_reading}}</td>
 <td> {{q2.powerfactor}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `q2` variable is just an object not a set.

The following line returns a single object -

```
KEBReading.objects.latest("date")
```

But your template is expecting a set that it can iterate over -

```
{% for item in q2 %}
 <tr>
 <td>{{item.date}}</td>
 <td>{{item.time}}</td>
 <td>{{item.truepower_reading}}</td>
 <td>{{item.apparentpower_reading}}</td>
  <td>{{item.truepower_consumed}}</td>
  <td>{{item.voltage_reading}}</td>
    <td> {{item.powerfactor}}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) for the `latest()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`latest()` returns the latest object in the table, not a set of objects. Instead of that, you should use `KEBReading.objects.all().order_by('date')`